# Search an id in python with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, module, beautifulsoup

I need help with a problem... I am doing a code for know the content of a tag but... What can I do for take the content if it have got a id?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

code = '<span class="vi-is1-prcp" id="v4-27"> 15,00 EUR </span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(code)
price = soup.find('a', id='v4-27')  # <-- PROBLEM
print price
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if that is the html code then you should replace the `'a'` tag with a `'span'` tag.  It should look something like this...

```
    ...
    price = soup.find('span',id="v4-27")
    print price #optional price.string will give you just the 15,00 EUR
                #instead of the entire html line
```

Comment: LOL, I need sleep o_O Thanks!